# Как сделать зеленый квадрат в этом месте?

Tags: html, css, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Начало кода даже писать не буду(легко)
Этот квадрат надо сделать с помощью CSS `float:right`
Когда задаю `float:right` квадрату и задаю отступ сверху там остается пустое место, текст не обтягивает квадрат сверху
Про `margin-left`, `right`, `bottom` знаю.

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот так получается не могу понять в чем ошибка. Заранее спасибо за помочь

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с использованием `shape-outside`

```css
.block {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.block__square {
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
  shape-outside: inset(65px 5px 75px 135px);
  clip-path: inset(65px 5px 75px 135px);
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__square"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos molestias tempora, minima harum alias odio sunt vel, numquam tenetur similique consectetur? Sint, aspernatur. Sit labore dolorum sequi. Voluptate, necessitatibus asperiores. Lorem
    ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, laudantium reiciendis quo non amet quaerat nobis, veritatis commodi, recusandae fugiat temporibus! Repellendus nulla aut commodi inventore, vitae explicabo cumque distinctio. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos molestias tempora, minima harum alias odio sunt vel, numquam tenetur similique consectetur? Sint, aspernatur. Sit labore dolorum sequi. Voluptate, necessitatibus asperiores. Lorem ipsum dolor sit
    amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt, laudantium reiciendis quo non amet quaerat nobis, veritatis commodi, recusandae fugiat temporibus! Repellendus nulla aut commodi inventore, vitae explicabo cumque distinctio.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Зря поощряете. Человек даже не попробовал сам что-то сделать.

Comment: @Quazimorda. Скорее всего вы правы, но мне самому стало интересно это реализовать.

Comment: Не надо удалять ответы.

Answer (score 1):

```css
body {
  text-align: justify;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

body::before {
  content: "";
  float: right;
  height: 3em;
}

div {
  clear: right;
  float: right;
  height: 6em;
  width: 6em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: .75em 0 .75em 1em;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum fugit dignissimos doloremque consectetur iste nihil in a quam minus. Minima possimus enim odit obcaecati eius? Quibusdam dolore ut quas nobis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum fugit dignissimos doloremque consectetur iste nihil in a quam minus. Minima possimus enim odit obcaecati eius? Quibusdam dolore ut quas nobis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum fugit dignissimos doloremque consectetur iste nihil in a quam minus. Minima possimus enim odit obcaecati eius? Quibusdam dolore ut quas nobis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum fugit dignissimos doloremque consectetur iste nihil in a quam minus. Minima possimus enim odit obcaecati eius? Quibusdam dolore ut quas nobis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum fugit dignissimos doloremque consectetur iste nihil in a quam minus. Minima possimus enim odit obcaecati eius? Quibusdam dolore ut quas nobis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum fugit dignissimos doloremque consectetur iste nihil in a quam minus. Minima possimus enim odit obcaecati eius? Quibusdam dolore ut quas nobis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum fugit dignissimos doloremque consectetur iste nihil in a quam minus. Minima possimus enim odit obcaecati eius? Quibusdam dolore ut quas nobis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum fugit dignissimos doloremque consectetur iste nihil in a quam minus. Minima possimus enim odit obcaecati eius? Quibusdam dolore ut quas nobis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum fugit dignissimos doloremque consectetur iste nihil in a quam minus. Minima possimus enim odit obcaecati eius? Quibusdam dolore ut quas nobis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum fugit dignissimos doloremque consectetur iste nihil in a quam minus. Minima possimus enim odit obcaecati eius? Quibusdam dolore ut quas nobis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum fugit dignissimos doloremque consectetur iste nihil in a quam minus. Minima possimus enim odit obcaecati eius? Quibusdam dolore ut quas nobis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ipsum fugit dignissimos doloremque consectetur iste nihil in a quam minus. Minima possimus enim odit obcaecati eius? Quibusdam dolore ut quas nobis.
```